# Yang Model recursive search for must condition

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

I have a problem with a restriction on my CLI. I've been investigating yang RFC7950 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950) but I've found nothing.

Here is an example.

```
grouping httpGroup {
  list http-list{
    key "value";
    leaf value {
      status current { yexte:preliminary; }
      description "value to match";
      must "(not(../protocol)) and (not(../network-port)))" {
        error-message "Not compatible with protocol or non-TCP ports";
      }
      type string { length "1..255"; }
    }
  }
}
```

This group will be included in several groups with the following structure:

```
list and {
  leaf-list protocol { ..... }
  uses A;
  list or { 
    leaf-list protocol { ..... }
    uses A;
  }
}
grouping A {
  status{}
  leaf-list protocol { ..... }
  leaf-list X { ..... }
  uses httpGroup;
}
```

I need this must condition included in httpGroup to verify that protocol value has **not** been configured in any level of the hierarchy.

I've made this be adding more relatives paths to search for this node:

```
// same level
not(../protocol)

// next level
not(../and/protocol)
not(../or/protocol)

// previous level
not(../../protocol)
not(../../protocol)

//recursively down previous level
not(../../and/protocol)
not(../../or/protocol)

// third level
not(../and/or/protocol)
not(../and/and/protocol)
```

As you can see, this is not a clean solution at all.

Is there any way it can be done for a whole hierarchy like:

```
if protocol node exists and http-list exists then error.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your structure example does not make sense. You cannot use grouping `A` within list `and`, since it attempts to define a duplicate `protocol` leaf-list child. Please clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupings are meant to be reusable. It is a bad practice to attempt to create a grouping that may only be used in specific contexts. This is exactly what happens if you define an XPath expression within a grouping and this expression references nodes that are "outside" this grouping (a not yet known ancestor data node, for example, or even worse - an ancestor with a specific name).

The proper way for you to handle this situation would be to use a refine statement in each different context where this grouping is used. You target the `value` leaf with it, then refine it by adding a must statement, the expression of which of course depends on usage context. You do **not** define a must statement within grouping `http-list`.

Within grouping `A`:

```
grouping A {
  status{}
  leaf-list protocol { ..... }
  leaf-list X { ..... }
  uses httpGroup {refine "http-list/value" {must "not(../../protocol)";}}
}
```

As you can see, grouping `A` is now completely self-sufficient and may be used within any context - the must will not have any problems with it.